# Input error in python

Tags: python, input

I am trying to make a simple calculator in python but I seem to get an input error whenever I try running it:

```
while True:
print("please choose one of these available options:\n\"add, subtract, multiply, divide, quit\"\ntype in exactly as shown or the calculator won't work");
choice = input();
if(choice == "quit"):
    break;
elif(choice == "divide"):
    num1 = float(input("Please enter a number:"));
    num2 = float(input("Please enter another number:"));
    output = num1/num2;
    print("The answer is:", output);
elif(choice == "multiply"):
    num1 = float(input("Please enter a number:"));
    num2 = float(input("Please enter another number:"));
    output = num1*num2;
    print("The answer is:", output);
elif(choice == "subtract"):
    num1 = float(input("Please enter a number:"));
    num2 = float(input("Please enter another number:"));
    output = num1-num2;
    print("The answer is:", output);
elif(choice == "add"):
    num1 = float(input("Please enter a number:"));
    num2 = float(input("Please enter another number:"));
    output = num1+num2;
    print("The answer is:", output);
else:
    print("Invalid Input. Try again");
```

When I run the code, the interpreter just shows: `NameError: name '...' is not defined` whenever I type something in (replace ellipsis with the input).

Can someone please see if I done anything wrong with the input, as that is the only thing that doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running the code with Python 3 and not Python 2?

Comment: I think that my iPad's interpreter might be running python 2.7

Comment: There's your issue. This code is suitable for python 3 but not python 2. If you can only run python 2.7, change `input` to `raw_input`

Comment: For the love of God, remove those ugly semicolons.

Comment: Sorry about the semicolons. I also do c++ and Java, so I just put them in subconsciously...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello user8311329,**

## Problem

When you use string as input so use `raw_input()` function. And all program you are use `;` so python provides functionality with out `;(colon)` to execute program.

## Solution

Try this code,

```
while True:
    print("please choose one of these available options: \n1. Add \n2. Subtract \n3. Multiply \n4. Divide \n5. Quit \nType in exactly as shown or the calculator won't work")
    choice = str(raw_input("From above choice any one option: "))

    if(choice == "quit"):
        break

    elif(choice == "divide"):
        num1 = float(input("Please enter a number:"))
        num2 = float(input("Please enter another number:"))
        output = num1/num2
        print "The answer is:",output

    elif(choice == "multiply"):
        num1 = float(input("Please enter a number:"))
        num2 = float(input("Please enter another number:"))
        output = num1*num2
        print "The answer is:",output

    elif(choice == "subtract"):
        num1 = float(input("Please enter a number:"))
        num2 = float(input("Please enter another number:"))
        output = num1-num2
        print "The answer is:",output

    elif(choice == "add"):
        num1 = float(input("Please enter a number:"))
        num2 = float(input("Please enter another number:"))
        output = num1+num2
        print "The answer is:",output

    else:
        print("Invalid Input. Try again")
```

I give suggestion for example if any other user run this use your application so this person don't understand what exactly enter in input so code write efficient and perfect so other user understand easily and give suggestion not use this code for string insert but use number enter for choice like i give example (I not give just simple example and you also add the more validation for input),

```
while True:
    print("please choose one of these available options: \n1. Add \n2. Subtract \n3. Multiply \n4. Divide \n5. Quit \nType in exactly as shown or the calculator won't work")
    try:
        choice = input("From above choice any one option: ")

        if(choice == 1):
            num1 = float(input("Please enter a number:"))
            num2 = float(input("Please enter another number:"))
            output = num1+num2
            print "The answer is:",output,"\n"

        elif(choice == 2):
            num1 = float(input("Please enter a number:"))
            num2 = float(input("Please enter another number:"))
            output = num1-num2
            print "The answer is:",output,"\n"

        elif(choice == 3):
            num1 = float(input("Please enter a number:"))
            num2 = float(input("Please enter another number:"))
            output = num1*num2
            print "The answer is:",output,"\n"

        elif(choice == 4):
            num1 = float(input("Please enter a number:"))
            num2 = float(input("Please enter another number:"))
            output = num1/num2
            print "The answer is:",output,"\n"


        elif(choice == 5):
            break

        else:
            print "Invalid Input. Try again\n"
    except:
        print "Invalid Input. Try again...\n"
```

I hope my answer is helpful.
If any query so comment please.

Answer (score 0):

just change input(), into raw_input(). raw_input() takes the input as string no matter what, in contrast to input(), which decides for you.

also, you can put the print inside the input:

```
choice = raw_input("please choose one of these available options:\n\"add, subtract, multiply, divide, quit\"\ntype in exactly as shown or the calculator won't work")
```

also, you don't need ';' at the end of every line in python